What is the proper error code when API parameter value(s) not match the endpoint?
Suppose the endpoints called:
/fruit
/meat
and there is a correct parameter called 'Farm', but parameter value pass to the endpoint is incorrect/out of boundary, in which that value is related to authentication/permission:
For example,
/meat?Farm=KingRanch return HTTP 200, as KingRanch is a meat farm.
what should be the proper error code for /fruit?Farm=KingRanch?
HTTP 400 with clear explanation that KingRanch is a meat farm, not a fruit farm? or HTTP 403?
Test in test env, having HTTP 403, but I am thinking if HTTP 400 is better.

Are you looking for 400 - Bad Request?

You should use error 400 with an explanation. If KingRange is a meat farm it has nothing to do with authentication as it is a business process characterisation and part of your validation rules on the data stating whether KingRange can handle fruit. (An authentication error would be if your credentials were incorrect.)
